# What means sed "1,\$s#.*/##" Linux bash

Tags: sed

i have a question, its new for me. I have to learn scripting in bash.
Can someone tell me what this line mean?

```
sed "1,\$s#.*/##"
```

I'm looking for it since 2 hours. Only i know (i think i know) is that from first word to end of line (because of `1,\$s`) then i dont know what means `#.*/##`   (`.` is single char, `*`>=0 and `#` comment, please correct me if im wrong). For example in this case:

```
213.241.37.114"/vol/1/ftp.cdlinux.pl/iso/v0.5/MD5SUM
```

it prints MD5SUM.

Comment: This has nothing to do with `bash`. It's a regular expression being processed by `sed`.

Comment: `#` is not a comment. It's the delimiter around the regular expression in the `s` command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `x,y` part is an **address** range, not a "word" range: it means from the first line to the last line. See [4 Addresses: selecting lines](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/sed-addresses.html#sed-addresses)

The `s///` command can use different delimiters than `/` -- in this case `#` is used. [3.3 The s Command](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/The-_0022s_0022-Command.html#The-_0022s_0022-Command)

In the whole file, we are searching for the regular expression `.*/` and replacing it with nothing -- getting the text after the last slash.

Comment: You should note that `1,$` is the default range, so this is redundant.

Comment: Okey, it's clear, but in my case is there difference between "1,\$s#.*/##" and "1,\$s#*/## ? (without .)

Comment: @Kawson That's a different question, and yes, there is a difference: `.*` means "any number of anything", but `*` on its own is a literal `*`.

Comment: ok so if i want to select single char, not all like .* i can use single . ?